# Jquery to find checkbox and execute a certain URL

Tags: jquery, html, spring

I'm new to this and I just started learning how to do web programming a few months ago. I'm having problems creating a jQuery so when a checkbox is clicked it will format and execute a url.

So the url will always be different depending on what checkboxes are clicked. For example, if you look at the picture down below and if the first three are checked the url will be

```
http://myspc.sc.ti.com/index.jsp?facility=DP1DM5&chart=EQ-ENASLA&chart=CL-NNT10KS&chart=CL-NNTPATS
```

And if another chart is checked it will need to be placed with the `&chart=CHARTNAME` in the url after the last `&chart=`

Here is the Standard URL Format: `http://myspc.sc.ti.com/index.jsp?facility=DP1DM5&chart=`**`CHARTNAME`**

I classify all the charts using **`${lot.chart}`**

So can someone please help me with this jQuery? Thank you in advance.

```
  <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="table-responsive table-responsive-data2">
                            <table class="table table-data2">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th><label class="au-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll"> <span class="au-checkmark"></span> </label></th>
                                        <th>Chart</th>
                                        <th>Top Lower</th>
                                        <th>Top Upper</th>
                                        <th>Bot Lower</th>
                                        <th>Bot Upper</th>
                                        <th>Resonse Spec</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr class="${status.count%2==0 ? 'tbl5' : 'tbl6'}">
        <c:forEach items="${lots}" var="lot" varStatus="status">
<<tr class="spacer"></tr>
                                        <tr class="tr-shadow">
<td><label class="au-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" id="1"> <span class="au-checkmark"></span></label></td>
<td class="status--processs"><a href= "http://myspc.sc.ti.com/index.jsp?facility=DP1DM5&chart=${lot.chart}" style="color: #000066" >${lot.chart} </a></td>

                                            <td><span class="status--process">${lot.topLower}</span></td>
                                            <td><span class="block-email">${lot.topUpper}</span></td>
                                            <td class="title-4">${lot.botLower}</td>
                                            <td class="desc">${lot.botUpper}</td>   

 <td class="desc"><a href= http://smsweb.sc.ti.com/SpecReports/AppServlet?action=getParagraphDetail&jspURL=reportParagraphDetail.jsp&facility=DP1DM5&paragraphId=${lot.responseSec}>${lot.responseSec}</a></td>
                                </tr>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>




    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#selectAll').click(function (e) {
        $(this).closest('table').find('td input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });

    $('checked-selector'.click (function(){
        window.location='url?chart=' + $ (this).val();
    }));

    $

</script>
</body>
>
```

Picture of Chart

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add class to your checkbox and add below method to get the URL. I have added "checkbox-selector" class to all the checkbox.

```
$('#selectAll').click(function (e) {
    $(this).closest('table').find('td input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
    checkboxCheck();
});

$('.checkbox-selector').on("change", checkboxCheck);

function checkboxCheck(){
    var url = "url?";
        $('.checkbox-selector:checked').each(function(){
        url+= "chart=" +$(this).closest("tr").find("a").first().text()+"&";
    })
    $("#url").text(url); // You can change the URL here..
}
```

I am adding snippet with the dummy data for the better understanding. This will also help you when you deselect checkbox (remove the name from the url).

```js
$('#selectAll').click(function (e) {
        $(this).closest('table').find('td input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
        checkboxCheck();
    });

    $('.checkbox-selector').on("change", checkboxCheck);
    
    function checkboxCheck(){
        var url = "url?";
      $('.checkbox-selector:checked').each(function(){
           url+= "chart=" +$(this).closest("tr").find("a").first().text()+"&";
        })
        $("#url").text(url);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="table-responsive table-responsive-data2">
                            <table class="table table-data2">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th><label class="au-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll"> <span class="au-checkmark"></span> </label></th>
                                        <th>Chart</th>
                                        <th>Top Lower</th>
                                        <th>Top Upper</th>
                                        <th>Bot Lower</th>
                                        <th>Bot Upper</th>
                                        <th>Resonse Spec</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr class="${status.count%2==0 ? 'tbl5' : 'tbl6'}">
        
<tr class="spacer"></tr>
                                        <tr class="tr-shadow">
<td><label class="au-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" id="1" class="checkbox-selector"> <span class="au-checkmark"></span></label></td>
<td class="status--processs"><a href= "http://myspc.sc.ti.com/index.jsp?facility=DP1DM5&chart=${lot.chart}" style="color: #000066" >a1</a></td>

                                            <td><span class="status--process">lot.topLower 1</span></td>
                                            <td><span class="block-email">lot.topUpper 1</span></td>
                                            <td class="title-4">lot.botLower 1</td>
                                            <td class="desc">lot.botUpper 1</td>   

 <td class="desc"><a href= http://smsweb.sc.ti.com/SpecReports/AppServlet?action=getParagraphDetail&jspURL=reportParagraphDetail.jsp&facility=DP1DM5&paragraphId=${lot.responseSec}>lot.responseSec 1</a></td>
                                </tr>
                                    <tr class="${status.count%2==0 ? 'tbl5' : 'tbl6'}">
        
<tr class="spacer"></tr>
                                        <tr class="tr-shadow">
<td><label class="au-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" id="2" class="checkbox-selector"> <span class="au-checkmark"></span></label></td>
<td class="status--processs"><a href= "http://myspc.sc.ti.com/index.jsp?facility=DP1DM5&chart=${lot.chart}" style="color: #000066" >a2</a></td>

                                            <td><span class="status--process">lot.topLower 2</span></td>
                                            <td><span class="block-email">lot.topUpper 2</span></td>
                                            <td class="title-4">lot.botLower 2</td>
                                            <td class="desc">lot.botUpper 2</td>   

 <td class="desc"><a href= http://smsweb.sc.ti.com/SpecReports/AppServlet?action=getParagraphDetail&jspURL=reportParagraphDetail.jsp&facility=DP1DM5&paragraphId=${lot.responseSec}>lot.responseSec 2</a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="${status.count%2==0 ? 'tbl5' : 'tbl6'}">
        
<tr class="spacer"></tr>
                                        <tr class="tr-shadow">
<td><label class="au-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" id="3" class="checkbox-selector"> <span class="au-checkmark"></span></label></td>
<td class="status--processs"><a href= "http://myspc.sc.ti.com/index.jsp?facility=DP1DM5&chart=${lot.chart}" style="color: #000066" >a3</a></td>

                                            <td><span class="status--process">lot.topLower 3</span></td>
                                            <td><span class="block-email">topUpper 3</span></td>
                                            <td class="title-4">lot.botLower 3</td>
                                            <td class="desc">lot.botUpper 3</td>   

 <td class="desc"><a href= http://smsweb.sc.ti.com/SpecReports/AppServlet?action=getParagraphDetail&jspURL=reportParagraphDetail.jsp&facility=DP1DM5&paragraphId=${lot.responseSec}>lot.responseSec 3</a></td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <br/><br/>
            <div id="url">
           
            </div>
```

You can test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/btwo17va/) as well..

Comment: Thank you Nimit Shah, this is what I needed! Is there any way to make it open that url in a new tab or window?

Comment: Thank you! I was able to figure it out.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to select all checkboxes and register an eventlistener for changeevents on each of them you gotta use...

```
$('input[type=checkbox']).on('ifChanged', function () {
    //... do whatever
    // $(this) is a reference to the jQuery object denoting the clicked checkbox
});
```

other than that you set the id for each checkbox to 1! that won't work since ids have to be unique. to differentiate the single clickable checkboxes that will execute some action from the first checkbox with id 'selectAll' I'd add a css class to them:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="action-checkbox">
```

and access them this way:

```
$('input.action-checkbox).on('click', function () {
    //... do whatever
    // $(this) is a reference to the jQuery object denoting the clicked checkbox
});
```